# Creating a json with multiple data type?

Tags: java, json

I have a requirement that I have to create a Json which look like this

```
{
  "method": "Main",
  "executeTime": 4,
  "arguments": [
    {
      "input": "input param"
    },
    {
      "output": "output string"
    }
  ],
  "error": null
}
```

Since it have multiple data types inside, so I made a hash map to handle them as objects, then I could use `GSON.toJson()` to get what I need. Here's my code

```
HashMap<String, Object> firstLayer = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, Object> secLayer = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

firstLayer.put("error", null);
firstLayer.put("method", <method String>);
firstLayer.put("executeTime", System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime);

secLayer.put("input", <input param string>);
list.add(secLayer);

secLayer = new HashMap<String, Object>();
secLayer.put("output", <output string>);
list.add(secLayer);

// JIT pops error here. This is unexpected.
firstLayer.add("arguments", list);
```

Error msg say: `The method add(String, List<HashMap<String,Object>>) is undefined for the type HashMap<String,Object>`. Even tried to use cast like `firstLayer.add("arguments", (Object)list);` but it still not right. Any other option or walkaround?

Comment: The message is correct, just as you use `firstLayer.put()` in all other lines, that single `firstLayer.add()` attempt should be `firstLayer.put()` too.

Comment: @tevemadar Wow, I used wrong function? maybe I worked too hard today. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I got it wrong, it is not `firstLayer.add("arguments", list);` but `firstLayer.put("arguments", list);`

I think I worked too hard today. Thanks #tevemadar